# WinForms application can't be closed using Process.CloseMainWindow

Tags: windows, winforms, process

I have a .Net 2.0 WinForms application that starts a second WinForms application using Process.Start and then later tries to close it again using Process.CloseMainWindow.

However the call to CloseMainWindow has no effect. The second application stays open even though it is fully responsive (and idle as far I can tell) and can immediately be closed manually.

Comment: More than one reason, UAC is certainly one of them.  Guessing at which window is the "main" one when an app creates more than one is fundamentally tricky as well.  That goes wrong when you do things like creating a splash screen or a login window.  Use Spy++ and compare Process.MainWindowHandle with the windows you see in the tool.

Comment: @HansPassant Right, Process.MainWindowHandle was being "guessed" wrong. What would be a safer way to close the Process?

Comment: Ask nicely instead of trying to hit it between the eyes with a sledge hammer.  A socket or named pipe or WCF is nice.

Comment: @HansPassant That sounds really nice, will consider it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans Passant suggested, the "main" window of the process to be closed was indeed being guessed wrong, so calling Process.CloseMainWindow did not have the intended effect.

Answer (score 0):

Set `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute=false` and check again.